# Can't fetch express API from React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express

I am now into my third week of trying to simply fetch a json response from an Express API into a React App. I have tried at least 40 hours of tutorials and I still can't get this to work. Out of desperation I am trying to post it here, knowing that I will be lynched as this will be a duplicate of some sort but I am looking for someone to go past this and hopefully help me understand what I am doing wrong.

**Anyway, here is the API I am trying to call:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('jestproject'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var todos = [{key:1, title:'eat'}, {key:2, title:'pray'}, {key:3, title:'love'}];

app.listen(3001, function (err) {
  if (err) {
  console.error('Cannot listen at port 3001', err);}
  console.log('Todo app listening at port 3001');
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).json(todos));

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.title) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'title is required'
        });
    }

    const todo = {
        key: todos.length + 1,
        title: req.body.title
    }

    todos.push(todo);
    return res.send({todo})
});

app.put('/:key', (req, res) => {

    var key = parseInt(req.params.key, 10);

    if (todos[key - 1]){
        todos[key -1] = { 'key': key, title : req.body.title };
        res.status(200).send({
            success: 'true',
            message: 'Todo updated successfully'
        });
    } 
    else{
        res.status(404, 'The task is not found')
        .send()
    }
});

app.get('/:key', (req, res) => {

    const key = parseInt(req.params.key, 10);

    todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.key === key) {
            return res.status(200).send({todo});
        }
    });

    return res.status(404).send({
        success: 'false',
        message: 'todo does not exist'
    });
});

app.delete('/:key', (req, res) => {

    const key = parseInt(req.params.key, 10);

    todos.map((todo, index) => {
        if (todo.key === key) {
            todos.splice(index, 1);
            return res.status(200).send({
                success: 'true',
                message: 'Todo deleted successfuly',
            });
        }
    });

    return res.status(404).send({
        success: 'false',
        message: 'todo not found',
    });
});

app.put('/:key', (req,res) => {
    const key = parseInt(req.params.key);

    if(todos.key === key) {
        todo = req.body;

        return res.status(200).send({
            success: 'true',
            message: 'Todo Updated successfully',
        });
    }
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Here is my latest attempt to call it from React**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
   constructor(){
       super();
       this.state ={key: 0, title: ''};
   }
   componentDidMount() {
          fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return res.json()
             })
            .then(todos => { 
                console.log(todos); 
                this.setState({ todos })
             });
         }
   render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>todos</h1>
                {this.state.todos.map(todo =>
                <div key = {this.state.key} > title: {this.state.title} </div>
              )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

This produces an error: ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***

Can someone please explain the proper way to just fetch data coming in this format?

Comment: you haven't initialized `this.state.todos` with an array.

Comment: What error are you getting with `fetch('http://localhost:3001/')`?

Comment: @palaѕн I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize todos in the constructor

```js
constructor(){
       super();
       this.state ={key: 0, title: '', todos: []};
   }
```

Because initially when the render method is called, the API is still in progress and at that time `todos` is undefined.

So when you try to run a `.map` on an undefined it crashes.

Comment: I fixed this but I now get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at fetch('http://localhost:3001/')

Answer (score 0):

your `todos` will be undefined during the initial `render` before `componentDidMount` runs, so you have to initialize the `todos` with the empty array like this

```
constructor(){
       super();
       this.state ={key: 0, title: '', todos: []};
   }
```

Comment: thanks! I fixed this but I now get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at fetch('localhost:3001/')

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed state and todos array.
In constructor initialize state like that:

```js
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state ={ todos: [key: 0, title: '']};
}
```

In render function:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>todos</h1>
                {this.state.todos.map(todo =>
                <div key = {todo.key} > title: {todo.title} </div>
              )}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: this produces an Error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis when using get function for  this.state ={ todos: [key: 0, title: '']}; 
Maybe it should be this.state ={ todos: {[key: 0, title: '']}};? Sorry I am extremely new to js and React